# CSSTYLE - option does not override standard values

Tags: css, sass

I have this code:

```
@include component(elementList) {
  tr {
    td {
      width: 50%;
      background: $darkGray;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    @include option(heading) {
        padding: 5px;
        background: #eeeeee;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    }
  }
}
```

It's just a table. And every row should have a dark background (which is saved in `$darkGray`), except for those rows with an option `--heading` set. Those should have a bright background.

But in my browsers, all rows are in the dark color. I also tried `!important` inside of the option.

Any ideas?

Thank you guys

PS: I am using  CSStyle with SASS.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the compiled CSS?

Comment: Yes, I did check the compiled CSS but found no solution for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this is a scoping issue. You use the dark background on table cells, while you're using the bright background on rows. So no matter which option the row has, its contained cells are dark.

This should work (untested and never used CSStyle)

```
@include component(elementList) {
  tr {
    td {
      width: 50%;
      background: $darkGray;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    @include option(heading) {
      td {
        padding: 5px;
        background: #eeeeee;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution